# Comparision of data in huge databases

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, vectorization

I have a database in mysql which has a collection of attributes (ex. 'weight', 'height', 'no of pages' etc) and attribute values (ex. '30 tons', '12 inches', '2 pgs' etc) and mapped with the respective product ids.
The data has been collected from different sites and hence the attribute values have different formats (ex. '222 pgs' or '222 pages' or '222') (ex2. '12 inches', '12 meters', '12 cms').
What I need to do is that I have to compare the values of same attributes of different products. So I have to compare '222 pgs' with '222 pages' for all the attributes which differ in formats.

There are around 4000 attributes and the number will increase further. Is there any way to compare these without having to assign each attribute a specific type individually? Or what is the fastest way to compare these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, until they invent a clairvoyant computer, a human being will have to tell it that `pgs` and `pages` mean the same thing and that `inches` and `meters` are convertible.

You'll have to sanitize the data one way or another. I'd probably start by identifying units that measure the same dimension<sup>1</sup> and common aliases<sup>2</sup> for each unit, then parse the data to split the quantity from the unit and normalize<sup>3</sup> the unit. Once you have done that, the data becomes directly comparable.

But all this is really just a remedy for the problem that should not have been there in the first place, were the database designed properly.

---

*<sup>1</sup> A "mass" is a dimension measured by units such as `kg`, `t`, `lb` etc. A "length" is a dimension measured by `m`, `km`, `in` etc.*

*<sup>2</sup> E.g. an `in` and `inch` denote exactly the same unit, `pgs` and `pages` are the same etc.*

*<sup>3</sup> I.e. make sure a particular dimension is always represented by the same unit: for example convert all lengths to `m`, all masses to `kg`, all pages to `pages` etc.*

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what you want to do after you find out that attributes for a pair of products differ (while still meaning the same thing).

I.e.: if I see that in Instance A has field Length  set to "12 pgs" and Instance B  has Length reporting "12 pages" what do you do? 
List this? Autocorrect? Drop one of the two values? Open a window for a human user to correct?

Personally I'd go for a "select attribute,count(*) from X group by attribute" so that you can find out the most common spelling of the unit, and then you can also write corrective scripts that may automatically convert ".. pgs" to " pages" as soon as you have decided the correct representation.

Of course this will not help at all unless you enforce correct spelling of the units, and this requires for sure better input-output filters, including the main UI, but also any kind of bulk uploader utility you may use to create or update products.

A redesign of the DB to add "Unit" as an extra, categorized attribute for each measure would also help a lot.